# how to iterate over the file and find the closest match between words [updated]?

Tags: python, dictionary, similarity

I am trying to find the closes match for the misspelled words from my correct words list (like look-up table). I have a code that uses leven (source: wikipedia) similarity on comparing 1 word with a look-up list and selects the best matched (also by defining the cost).

my word list looks like correctList.txt:

```
words = ['computer','test','right','tesla','omega','energy']
```

Based on the two input required by Levenshtein similarity, I provide input of:

```
userInput = 'compute'
limitSearch = int('3')

output = check(userInput, limitSearch)
for result in output: 
    print ('\n closeMatches: ', result)
```

Now I want to expand this and instead of checking one written misspelled word with the look-up dictionary, use the list of misspelled words (similar to the following file) and compare it with my correct list.txt and substitutes the best matches.

example of my misspelled.txt:

```
misspelled = ['computee','teste','righ','tessla','oomega','energie']
```

It would be great if you can help.

Answer (score 0):

I literally just made something like this about an hour ago. I used a module called leven to do it. I made it in repl.it because I was on a Chromebook. [Here is a link to it](https://repl.it/@hippolippo/Autocomplete) for if you want to look at it.

Comment: thanks for your comment and link. it is very useful. I guess it works the same as mine. Is there any idea that you can help me to my code works too?

Comment: @Bilgin the function that I call in the for loop will return the "`cost`" value you are trying to use, If you iterate through all the possible words, you can use the one with the lowest cost.

Comment: ok. I tried to run your code (as it is very straightforward) but I couldn't able to run it. I made sure that I installed ```pip install leven``` and run the code as ``` correct(leven, amount=5)```. Can you provide some guide for running your code?

Comment: The function is called levenstein but I set distance equal to levenstein

Comment: You need to provide a string into the function, you do not need to include the `amount = 5` unless you are making it something other than 5